# Merge multiindex pandas dataframes on a lagged datetimeindex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index, datetimeoffset

I am having difficulty:

1. Merging two pandas multiindex dataframes
2. Passing an offset to a datetimeindex in the merge

df1:

```
date        ID   Attr_1
12/31/2010  13   A
             9   B
             1   C
1/31/2011   13   D
             9   E
             1   F
```

df2:

```
date        ID   Attr_2
12/31/2010  13  -0.124409
             9   0.555959
             1  -0.705634
1/31/2011   13   0.471078
             9   0.276006
             1  -0.468463
```

A one-month lagged Attr_2 should be merged to df1. Desired output:

```
date        ID   Attr_1  Attr_2
12/31/2010  13   A       nan
             9   B       nan
             1   C       nan
1/31/2011   13   D      -0.124409             
             9   E       0.555959
             1   F      -0.705634
```

I would like to use:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2['Attr_2'], left_on = ['date', 'ID'], 
         right_on = [df2.index.date - pd.DateOffset(months = 1), 'ID'],
         how='left')
```

I cannot join on 'date' as it is an index in both dfs. I also cannot subtract the offset to the df2 `right_on` as I have done.

I have tried unsuccessfully resetting the index in both dfs, and then applying the offset to the `right_on` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This involve reconstruct your index

```
df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(pd.to_datetime(x[0]), x[1]) for x in df1.index])
df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(pd.to_datetime(x[0])+ pd.DateOffset(months = 1), x[1]) for x in df2.index])

df1.join(df2)
Out[413]: 
              Attr_1    Attr_2
2010-12-31 13      A       NaN
           9       B       NaN
           1       C       NaN
2011-01-31 13      D -0.124409
           9       E  0.555959
           1       F -0.705634
```

Comment: Is there a way of changing the index for df2 in the merge/join method itself?  Reason is I don't want to modify the original df2 index as I will make multiple calls to it with different time lags, ie 12M, 24M.

Comment: @akr24 you can make a copy of df2 , like df2_original =df2.copy(), then doing what every youwant for df2 :-)